# regex to find pattern not inside another pattern

Tags: css, regex, notepad++

I'm trying to write a regex to find all ID selectors in a CSS file. Basically, that means any word that starts with a #, so okay

```
#\w+
```

Except ... color specifiers can also start with a #. So what I really want is all words that start with a # that are NOT between { and }. I can't figure out how to say this.

I'm doing this in Notepad++ so I need that flavor of regex.

BTW my real objective is to delete everything that's not an ID selector from the file, so I end up with just a list of selectors. My first try was

```
Find: [^#]*(#\w+)
Replace: \1\r\n
```

... and then hit Replace All.

But then I ran into the color problem.

*Update*

Someone asks for an example. Ok:

Input:

```
.foo {max-width: 500px;}
#bar {text-align: left;}
.splunge, #plugh {color: #ff0088;}
```

Desired output:

```
#bar
#plugh
```

Note the point is that it includes the two "pound strings" that come outside of braces but not the one that comes inside braces.

Comment: `#\w+(?!\s*})` may work for you

Comment: Considering FFFFFF is a valid HTML ID, I don't see how you could possibly differentiate the two.  What kind of ID's are you targeting?  Are you specifically looking for ID's that are the target of a call to a method? (e.g. `$("#myID")`, `document.querySelector("#myID")`, etc.) knowing your goal or desired outcome may help us suggest alternative ideas.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Yes, I quickly realized I couldn't base the test on "looks like a valid color code". #FFFFFF may be an unlikely ID, but certainly not impossible. And, say, #BAD or #FACE02 could certainly turn up. That's why I was thinking that if it's between braces, than I could say it's not an ID and so not interesting. I guess that could skip media queries, now that I think about it.

Comment: @JosephMarikle My ultimate goal is that I have to find all CSS that references an ID, and that ID is in a Visual Basic user control. Possible to go at it from the other direction: find all the IDs in VB UCs and then search the CSS for them. I'm not sure that that would be any easier.

Comment: @Jay  so if you're trying to specifically exclude colors in CSS, couldn't you check for a preceding `:` character?  It wouldn't work for CSS declarations on multiple lines, though.

Comment: Looks like that won't work either.  Notepadd++ doesn't seem to fully support negative look behinds.

Comment: Hmm, though that leads to ... as my goal is to delete everything that's not an ID, maybe I can first delete everything that is a color, i.e. search for :\s*#\w+\s*; Then make a second pass to find the IDs.

Comment: Do you have selectors like: 'body, #myid' all on one line?

Comment: Could you show sample input and expected result?

Answer (score 3):

What about this? You could use a lookahead expression:

`#\w+(?=[^}]*?{)`

It ensures that a `{` follows the match (indicating that the match is part of a selector), but not after a `}` character (excluding any matches against color declarations in the CSS).

- `#`: match must begin with a `#`
- `\w+`: match one or more word characters (might need tweaked.  `\w` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`)
- `(?=...)`: positive lookahead
- `[^}]*?`: Any character not matching `}`
- `{`: the `{` character

https://regex101.com/r/Di43hX/3